# Count specific fields with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following schema:

```
create table myapp_task
(
  title varchar(100) not null,
  state varchar(11) not null,
  estimate date not null,
  my_id int not null auto_increment
  primary key,
  road_map_id int not null,
  create_date date not null,
  constraint myapp_task_road_map_id_5e114978_fk_myapp_roadmap_rd_id
  foreign key (road_map_id) references myapp_roadmap (rd_id)
);
— auto-generated definition
create table myapp_roadmap
(
  rd_id int not null auto_increment
  primary key,
  name varchar(50) not null
);
```

I want get number, begin and end of a week of create_date, number of all tasks and number of ready tasks (state = 'ready/in_progress')

Here is my query:

```
select DISTINCT week(create_date, 1) as week,
  SUBDATE(create_date, WEEKDAY(create_date)) as beginofweek,
  DATE(create_date + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(create_date)) DAY) as endofweek,
  SUM(state) as number,
  SUM(state = 'ready') as ready
from myapp_task 
inner join myapp_roadmap
  on myapp_task.road_map_id = myapp_roadmap.rd_id;
```

Actually, I have a problem only with count of ready tasks.

Comment: Is that really such a big ask to specify what exactly is your problem with the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are close:

```
select week(create_date, 1) as week,
    SUBDATE(create_date, WEEKDAY(create_date)) as beginofweek,
    DATE(create_date + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(create_date)) DAY) as endofweek,
    count(state) as number,
    SUM(CASE WHEN state = 'ready' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ready,
    SUM(CASE WHEN state = 'in_progress' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as in_progress
FROM myapp_task inner join myapp_roadmap
    on myapp_task.road_map_id = myapp_roadmap.rd_id
GROUP BY week, beginofweek, endofweek
```

Using a `CASE` statement you can add up just `states` that are `ready` or `in_progress` separately. Furthemore, the addition of a GROUP BY insures that the count is for the week. I think MySQL would probably spit out the right result without the GROUP BY in this case, but why let it guess at what you want here. Also, if you upgrade to MySQL 5.7+ then a query like this written without  a GROUP BY will error by default.

---

Also got rid of that DISTINCT modifier. Thanks @AaronDietz

Comment: Can get rid of that `DISTINCT` modifier now, too.

Comment: Thanks @AaronDietz I didn't even see that sneaky nogoodnick in there.

Comment: I like it, I always use `COUNT`. I'd never thought of using a `CASE` statement inside `SUM` but it works nicely.

Comment: number always equals 0 for some reason

Comment: @AarontDietz that's true.

Comment: @СергейТеплухин Insure that it's `COUNT(state)` and not `SUM(state)` I didn't catch that until a minute after submitting the answer.

Comment: @Sinfieldd I believe you could get away with `COUNT(CASE WHEN state='Ready' THEN state ELSE NULL)` but that seems more like it's relying on the RDBMS' behavior of not counting null values and isn't so obvious (Does that work in every RDBMS?)

Comment: @JNevill@SinfielddIn this case sum(state = 'ready') as ready also works well.

Comment: Thanks @СергейТеплухин I was wondering if that was just a wrong attempt, or if that worked. I haven't tried that in MySQL before and I know it doesn't work in most other RDBMS's. That is a REALLY nice feature. I've longed for boolean math in every other database I've worked in. Very nice to know!

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the use of [aggregate functions](http://www.sqlcourse2.com/agg_functions.html)

`COUNT` is the function to return the number of rows, and to get two values for the total number of states and those which are equal to 'ready', you need to join the table twice with different join conditions.

The columns that are then not aggregated need to be included in a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select DISTINCT week(create_date, 1) as week,
SUBDATE(create_date, WEEKDAY(create_date)) as beginofweek,
DATE(create_date + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(create_date)) DAY) as endofweek,
COUNT(r1.state) AS number, 
COUNT(r2.state) AS ready
from myapp_roadmap inner join myapp_task r1
on r1.road_map_id = myapp_roadmap.rd_id
inner join myapp_task r2
on r2.road_map_id = myapp_roadmap.rd_id and r2.state = 'ready'
group by week, beginofweek, endofweek
```